# Django user signup using custom user model not working

Tags: python, django, django-class-based-views, django-users

I have a Django custom user model 'es_user' which inherit the Django's default user model. when a user signup it works fine but that user will be part of 'Users' and nothing will add upto es_user. so each time a user sign up I've to go to admin panel and add a signed in 'User' to 'es_user'.

So to solve that I added these 2 to lines to **views.py**

```
 es_user_instance = es_user.objects.create(user= req_user)
 es_user_instance.save()
```

which gives me this error

```
ValueError at /signup/

Cannot assign "<SimpleLazyObject: <django.contrib.auth.models.AnonymousUser object at 0x7f9c787b9be0>>": "es_user.user" must be a "User" instance.
```

**models.py**

```
class es_user(models.Model):
user = models.OneToOneField(User,related_name='es_user', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

**views.py**

```
def signup(request):
signup_form_instance = SignUpForm()

if request.method == "POST":

    signup_form_instance = SignUpForm(request.POST)
    if signup_form_instance.is_valid():
        signup_form_instance2 = signup_form_instance.save(commit = False)
        req_user = request.user
        signup_form_instance2.password = make_password(signup_form_instance.cleaned_data['password'])
        signup_form_instance2.save()
        es_user_instance = es_user.objects.create(user= req_user)
        es_user_instance.save()

        return index(request)#successful signup redirect or return
    else:
        print("SIGN UP FORM INVALID")

return render(request,'signup.html',{'signup_form':signup_form_instance})
```

**forms.py**

```
class SignUpForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'email', 'password')
```

can somebody tell me where is the problem

**NOTE:** I've used this custom user model because I will be adding many more fields to 'es_user' later on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `req_user = request.user` is returning an `AnonymousUser` because you haven't logged in the user yet. So before using `request.user`, [login the user](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/auth/default/#how-to-log-a-user-in) first.

Alternatively, you could just add the user you just created without logging it in:

```
es_user_instance = es_user.objects.create(user=signup_form_instance2)
```

Comment: thanks @damores I've tried both of your suggested methods it's working fine